# The best way to plot time series data for a short period of time

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, time-series, visualization

I have a dataset with two columns "new_date" and "Sales". The dataset captures the daily sales for a company over 3 months in just one year 2020, "i.e., Jan, Feb, and March". The size of the dataset is about 8000 rows. One day might have different transaction or different sales.

```
 new_date     Sales
2020-01-26     453
2020-01-26     232
2020-02-03     123
2020-02-03     223
2020-03-13     333
2020-03-23     657
```

My question is that is it possible to plot the time series for this short period date? And what is the best choice.

I simply tried to use plot

```
df.plot(legend=False)
```

But the results is not as good as I was expect.

[image]

Is there any better way to visualize and organize this time series data?

Comment: Maybe checkout seaborn and plotly. They are usually the cleanest time series tools for such analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are exactly looking for, but based on the data I guess you could sum the `Sales` first by `new_date`.

```
df.groupby('new_date').sum().plot(legend=False)
```

When you want to sum `Sales` per week, you can use `resample`:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'new_date' : pd.date_range('2022-01-01', '2022-03-31'),
    'Sales' : random.sample(range(100, 1000), 90)}).set_index('new_date')

df.resample('W').sum().plot(legend=False)
```

Comment: Is there a way to plot the Sales by week of the year instead? So we have in total 12 weeks (4 weeks in Jan, 4 in Feb and 4 in March)

Comment: I added `resample per week` to my answer. Expect this is what you are looking for.